# MissingMethodException when applied generic type parameters to method that returns generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, exception, invoke, mono.cecil

I have a method called DynamicInvoke that is as follows:

```
public static object InvokeDynamic(Delegate d, object[] args)
{
    Type[] tparams = d.Method.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()
                        .Concat(d.Method.GetGenericArguments())
                        .ToArray();
    Type dt = d.GetType().DeclaringType;
    if (dt.ContainsGenericParameters)
        dt = dt.MakeGenericType(tparams);
    IDirectInvoke di = dt.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null) as IDirectInvoke;
    object o = di.Invoke(d.Method, d.Target, args);
    return o;
}
```

It is used in the following context (and yes this is programmatically generated code using Mono.Cecil and reversed using ILSpy):

```
[Processed, Distributed]
[Serializable]
public class GenericsTest<A, B> : ITransparent, ISerializable where A : new() where B : ITest
{
    private class Method3__InvokeDirect3<C> : IDirectInvoke
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        public delegate C Method3__DistributedDelegate4();
        public object Invoke(MethodInfo method, object instance, object[] parameters)
        {
            GenericsTest<A, B>.Method3__InvokeDirect3<C>.Method3__DistributedDelegate4 method3__DistributedDelegate = (GenericsTest<A, B>.Method3__InvokeDirect3<C>.Method3__DistributedDelegate4)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(GenericsTest<A, B>.Method3__InvokeDirect3<C>.Method3__DistributedDelegate4), instance, method);
            return method3__DistributedDelegate.Invoke();
        }
    }
    public C Method3<C>()
    {
        MulticastDelegate d = new GenericsTest<A, B>.Method3__InvokeDirect3<C>.Method3__DistributedDelegate4(this.Method3__Distributed0<C>);
        object[] args = new object[0];
        return (C)DpmEntrypoint.Invoke(d, args);
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private C Method3__Distributed0<C>()
    {
        return default(C);
    }
}
```

Now the code operates correctly if either a) GenericsTest has no generic parameters or b) the method has no generic parameters (and I have other classes and methods that verify this).  Only when both the class and the methods contain generic parameters does the problem occur.

When di.Invoke is called, I get the following exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  Message="Method not found: '**UNKNOWN TYPE** Method3__DistributedDelegate4.Invoke()'."
  Source="Examples.ServerClient"
  StackTrace:
       at Examples.ServerClient.GenericsTest`2.Method3__InvokeDirect3`1.Invoke(MethodInfo method, Object instance, Object[] parameters)
       at Process4.Providers.DpmEntrypoint.InvokeDynamic(Delegate d, Object[] args) in C:\Server Storage\Projects\Redpoint\Dx\Process4\Providers\Dpm.cs:line 249
       at Process4.Providers.DpmEntrypoint.Invoke(Delegate d, Object[] args) in C:\Server Storage\Projects\Redpoint\Dx\Process4\Providers\Dpm.cs:line 359
       at Examples.ServerClient.GenericsTest`2.Method3[C]()
       at Examples.ServerClient.Program.GenericsTest() in C:\Server Storage\Projects\Redpoint\Dx\Examples.ServerClient\Program.cs:line 76
       at Examples.ServerClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Server Storage\Projects\Redpoint\Dx\Examples.ServerClient\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Given that I've checked the results in ILSpy and the IL and metadata is functionally equivalent to that generated by the C# compiler itself (tested by copying the code into a .cs file and compiling it), I'm now thinking that it's the runtime use of the Invoke method that's causing this issue.

One of the odd effects is that the constructor is called successfully AND Visual Studio reports the types correctly when inspecting the newly created IDirectInvoke object (it only throws the exception when calling Invoke) and yet as noted previously, the IL for Invoke is identical to what C# generates.

Does anyone know what the issue could be in this case?

**EDIT:** One more thing, this only occurs on methods that directly return a generic parameter assigned to a method (so it does not occur if the method returns A, B or another generic type instance that contains parameters of A, B or C; in this case it occurs because the method directly returns an object of type C).